# Efficient way to solve "Partition Function Q" or total number of sequences which sum to n

Tags: java, performance, recursion

The problem is this: how many sequences can you make with a minimum of 2 numbers where all numbers in the sequence sum to n.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html

Using the equation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/508630)* I was able to get the following function:

```
public static int GetSequences(int n, int k) {
    if(n <= k) return 0;
    int result = 1;
    for(int i = k + 1; i < n; i++) {
        result += GetSequences(n - i, i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

But the time to solve is exponential with n. At around `n = 180` it can take 10+ seconds to finish.

I have tried using a hashmap to store previously solved values but I was getting pretty wild results.

```
static Map<Long,Long> cache = new HashMap<Long,Long>();

public static int solve(int n) {
    for(int i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
        cache.put((long)i, (long)GetSequences(i, 0));
    }
    return cache.get((long) n).intValue() - 1;
}

public static int GetSequences(int n, int k) {
    if(n <= k) return 0;
    if(cache.containsKey((long)k)) {
        return cache.get((long)k).intValue();
    }
    int result = 1;
    for(int i = k + 1; i < n; i++) {
        result += GetSequences(n - i, i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

How can I improve the efficiency in order to generate the total number of sequences faster?

*: In order for the `GetSequences(n,k)` function to solve the problem in the link, the result must be subtracted by 1 to account for the sequence `[n,0]`

Comment: "I have tried using a hashmap to store previously solved values but I was getting pretty wild results." - you had a bug. Whatever it was, find it and fix it.

Comment: @user2357112 I added what I think I had before for hashmaps, I will look deeper into what was causing the issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure longs aren't going to cut it here.

Comment: @user2357112 It doesn't, not for long anyways. After `n = 225` the result overflows for integers which is really the datatype that I am working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it using memoization. In this approach whenever you solve a subproblem you store the result so that whenever subproblem repeats, you just do a lookup instead of computation.

Below program should give you some idea. Its not an very efficient solution but it does reduce running time considerably.

```
public class Partition {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(GetSequences(180, 1, new HashMap<>()));
    }

    public static int GetSequences(int n, int k, Map<Pair, Integer> data) {
        if (n <= k)
            return 0;

        int result = 1;

        for (int i = k + 1; i < n; i++) {
            Pair p = new Pair(n - i, i);
            if (data.containsKey(p)) {
                result += data.get(p);
            } else {
                int res = GetSequences(n - i, i, data);
                data.put(p, res);
                result += res;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    static class Pair {
        int n;
        int k;

        Pair(int n, int k) {
            this.n = n;
            this.k = k;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + k;
            result = prime * result + n;
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Pair other = (Pair) obj;
            if (k != other.k)
                return false;
            if (n != other.n)
                return false;
            return true;
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: Looks like a major flaw in my use of the hashmap (probably along with others) was that I had to compare the previous value and also the remainder in order to use the result. I was only comparing the remainder which was throwing my results off. Great solution

Answer (score 1):

You can also forgo recursion entirely and use the generating function shown on the [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html) page, which boils down to polynomial arithmetic. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1972048/368127) for an explanation and a Java implementation which I've re-produced below. Also, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176397/368127) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/245615/368127) for another helpful walkthrough of the how to implement the arithmetic for specific for type of polynomial.

```
static long Q(int n) {
    return QArray(n)[n];
}

// Computes Q(i) for i = 0..n
//
// The following implementation uses the generating function:
//
//      Sum (Q(i)*x^i) = Product (1 + x^t)
//
// for i = 0,1,2...  and  t = 1,2,3...
//
// `poly` below is an array of coefficients for x^0,x^1,x^2...x^n.
// Terms above x^n in the infnite series are ignored.
static long[] QArray(int n) {
    assert n >= 0: n;

    long[] poly = new long[n + 1];
    poly[0] = 1;

    for (int t = 1; t <= n; t++)
        for (int exp = n; exp >= t; exp--) // multiply by (1 + x^t)
            poly[exp] += poly[exp - t];

    return poly;
}
```

A `long` will be good for `n < 770`, after which you should switch to using `BigInteger`.

The generating function approach requires `O(n^2)` additions and enough space to store the values up to `Q(n)`. Code very similar to the above can also be used to compute partition functions `P(n)`, `P(n, k)`, and `Q(n, k)` as well.